# Does the briefcase in Pulp Fiction contain a Silmaril?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, pulp-fiction-1994

The movie Pulp Fiction centers around a mysterious briefcase, the contents of which is described as shining with an inner light and is so beautiful it captivates anyone who looks at it.

Marsellus Wallace really wants to get it, which is in line with the [Oath of Fëanor](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Oath_of_F%C3%ABanor) that the sons of Fëanor were bound by, namely to recover their father's Silmarils.

Jules Winnfield keeps quoting Ezekiel 25:17, which isn't actually Ezekiel 25:17 but is instead a description of Maglor's (son of Fëanor) life.

> The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides by the inequities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men. Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of the darkness, for he is truly his brother’s keeper and the finder of lost children. And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt to poison and destroy my brothers.

During the First Age, Maglor ruled in “[Maglor’s Gap](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Maglor%27s_Gap)”, the valley between Morgoth's domain and the lands of the Elves. He held this valley for 450 years until Morgoth finally conquered it. Once this happened, Maglor led the retreat of his people, thereby “shepherding the weak through the valley of darkness”.

He then fled to his brother Maedhros' fortress in Himling where he helped defend Maedhros’ lands and people, thereby making him “his brother’s keeper”.

During this time, he adopted the young Elrond and Elros, who had been orphaned after their parents fled across the sea, thereby making him “the finder of lost children”.

And finally “striking down with great vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt to poison and destroy my brothers”, is what he spent quite a lot of time doing in defending his brother's land.

Maglor is possibly the only [Noldo](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Noldor) still remaining in the world and if he were still alive in our times, he would remain bound by the Oath of Fëanor and be hunting the Silmaril.

[Maglor's mother-name is “Makalaurë”](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Makalaur%C3%AB), which means that “Marsellus” is barely even a pseudonym. There is even precedent of beings in Middle-earth masking their true appearance (*cough* Sauron *cough*). Thus allowing a lithe, fair-skinned, Elf to be a bald, black, man.

So could it have been a Silmaril in the briefcase that Maglor had to find again after someone recovered it from sea where he had thrown it?

Comment: This question should not be closed as primarily opinion based as it does not ask for opinions but whether there is a basis in canon.

Comment: Is it April 1st today!?!?

Comment: This movie doesn't seem to contain any overtly supernatural themes or premises; https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-has-the-greatest-chance-of-being-in-marcellus-wallaces-briefcase - At best we're told that the briefcase can stand-in for the supernatural *if we, the audience want it to*.

Comment: Now I'm going to be mentally hearing "motherf---er"s all over the place when I read one of Tolkein's several-page songs or poems.  Besides, it's clearly an Infinity Stone.

Comment: Is this an attempt to game the hat system or something?

Comment: Well yeah, isn't it obvious enough in the movie though?  Seems silly to even ask.

Answer (score 9):

No, I think you are stretching it a bit too much here.

- Something "shining with an inner light and is so beautiful it captivates anyone who looks at it" is a common enough trope that I don't think it has to refer to a Silmaril. The Silmaril is not even the only piece of jewelry in Middle-earth that captivates anyone who looks at it (is it, precious).
- The messed up quote from Ezekiel is general enough that it could apply to a great many characters. It's the sort of thing a fortune teller might come up with.
- I'm not sure what connection you are drawing between "Makalaure" (meaning gold-cleaver" and refering to the golden music of his harp) and "Marsellus" ("Marcellus" apparently means hammer).
- Although he could have changed his mind in the intervening millennia, Maglor cast his Silmaril **into** the sea.

Answer (score 6):

While there's some reasonably good arguments here (as much as it pains me to say) as Blackwood says, some of these are a bit of a stretch. Especially the idea of Maglor reclaiming the Silmaril he'd cast into the Sea, since we know (if you believe in the Dagor Dagorath) that only then are the two lost Silmarils reclaimed, and only then does Eärendil come down from the heavens.

> The Silmarils shall be recovered, and their light released, the Trees rekindled, the Mountains of Valinor levelled so that the light goes out over all the world, and Gods and Elves shall grow young again.
>   <sub>History of Middle-earth - Volume 4, The Shaping of Middle-earth</sub>

Maglor, or anyone else, could not have claimed back the Silmaril in time for the taking place of the events of Pulp Fiction since they would have occurred before Dagor Dagorlad, the *Last Battle*.

Answer (score 4):

No because no one would have been able get it out of the sea

> "And Varda hallowed the Silmarils, so that thereafter no mortal flesh,
>   nor hands unclean, nor anything of evil will might touch them, but it
>   was scorched and withered" - The Silmarillion.

The only time someone could touch it without the pain was when Beren took one, because the jewel let him.

> "As he closed it in his hand, the radiance welled through his living
>   flesh, and his hand became as a shining lamp; but the jewel suffered
>   his touch and hurt him not." - The Silmarillion.

So the Silmaril probably would not have let itself be taken out of the sea.

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that Maglor was able to hold the Silmaril well enough to throw it into the sea in the first place.

Comment: But why would he want to get it back out? He knows better than anyone the problems it causes.

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: He supposedly spent the rest of his life wanting to reclaim it, and it burnt him, which is why he cast it into the sea.

Comment: @Blackwood - Marcellus Wallace = Maglor?  I jokingly said it was obviously an Infinity Stone, not a Silmaril, but maybe Silmaril = Infinity Stone?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as a "what if ...", and Mia does appear to use the power of illusion when they arrive at the restaurant, beside the similarity of her name to "Maia", but "the Silmarillion" makes it pretty clear that the lost Silmarils won't be recovered until Dagor Dagorath.